# how to get data on month base from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have data in the following form

Array
    (

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [event_id] => 2042632
        [event_name] => Georgia Tech Yellow Jackets vs. North Carolina Tar Heels
        [event_payment] => 156
        [payment_status] => 1
        [event_date] => 2014-01-29
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [event_id] => 2042632
        [event_name] => Georgia Tech Yellow Jackets vs. North Carolina Tar Heels
        [event_payment] => 89
        [payment_status] => 1
        [event_date] => 2014-01-29
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [event_id] => 2042632
        [event_name] => Georgia Tech Yellow Jackets vs. North Carolina Tar Heels
        [event_payment] => 772
        [payment_status] => 1
        [event_date] => 2014-01-29
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [event_id] => 2042633
        [event_name] => Georgia Tech Yellow Jackets vs. North Carolina Tar Heels
        [event_payment] => 256
        [payment_status] => 0
        [event_date] => 2013-12-29
    )

)
```

All I want now to show data in the following format after getting from this array:

```
January

Event-name, payment, status
georgia..   1234,    0
georgia..   3456,    1

December

Event-name, payment, status
georgia..   1234,    0
georgia..   3456,    1
```

and so on and so forth.

please guide me how to do that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$result = array();
foreach($arr as $ar){
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $ar['event_date']);
 $month = $date->format('F');
 $year = $date->format('Y');
 $result[$year][$month][] = $ar;
}
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/98935)

Answer (score 2):

```
$res= array();
foreach($arr as $key => $val) // $arr is your actual array
{
    $month = date('F-Y', strtotime($val['event_date']));
    $res[$month][] = $val;
}
```

Now you get will result as

```
[January-2014] = array(a1,a2...)
[December-2014] = array(a1,a2...)
```

Comment: This code won't work properly since dates in the array belong to different years (2013, 2014).

Answer (score 0):

Here I only suggest how to sort an array by date. I hope you can do the rest of the work yourself.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return (new DateTime($a['event_date']))->getTimestamp() < (new DateTime($b['event_date']))->getTimestamp()? -1 : 1;
}
usort($array, 'cmp');

$curr_month = 0;
foreach ($array as $elem) {
    // output elements of array based on month
    // ...
}
```